# on sign up if email already exist then render user on specific page where i can display some message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i just want to send confirmation instructions to user again if email already exist.

Thats what i've implemented, it just let user to sign Up if email is unique. if email already exist it just don't do anything.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout 'pages'
  def new
    build_resource
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    admin = User.create(first_name: "")
    resource.authenticatable = admin
    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: accounts_get_started_path(resource)
      end
    else
      byebug
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  def edit
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  def destroy
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: anybody can help me out with that?

Comment: You can use `resource.valid?` It will be the same as user.valid?.

Comment: @sk1712 can you please explain a little more in code form in my code where and what should i use to get the results?

Comment: @sk1712 guide here please???

Answer (score 0):

If the email already exists you should resend devise confirmation mail by doing this:

```
Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(resource).deliver
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **valid?** runs all the validations within the specified context. Returns *true* if no errors are found, otherwise it returns *false*. (Refer to this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/valid%3F) for more info.)

**NOTE:** Here I am assuming you have **uniqueness** validation on **email** field. (Refer this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of) for more info)

If you have validation, then your code looks like

```
def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)
  .
  .
  if resource.valid?
    # your code for saving details
  else
    # Your code to redirct to different page
    redirect_to where_you_want
  end
end
```